# WebView Orientation Change not resizing Webpage

Tags: android, html, webview, resize

I'm making an android app and if I am at the very top of my WebView and I try to switch my phone into landscape mode, then it wont resize the webpage to fit my phones screen. It will only take up half of the screen, but then if I scroll down a little bit and switch to landscape mode it works fine!

I have `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the Android Manifest to keep the webview from resetting when i do change the orientation.

^^Note^^
Even if you are a tenth of a inch from the top of the page it will work fine, but if you are all the way at the top of the page it won't work.

This is the class im having problems with:

```
package my.app.name;

import my.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ConverterCatalogActivity extends Activity {
    WebView browser;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Set the Content View */
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* Get the WebView */
        WebView wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);

        /* Activate JavaScript */
        wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.canGoBack();
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv1);
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        /* Prevent WebView from Opening the Browser */
        wv1.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // We do nothing here. We're only handling this to keep orientation
        // or keyboard hiding from causing the WebView activity to restart.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(browser.canGoBack()){
                browser.goBack();
                return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


/* Class that prevents opening the Browser */
private class InsideWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Here's a screenshot of it in landscape mode.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with WebViews doing this before.  Try measuring the view in `OnOrientationChanged` and it may fix your problem!

Comment: Can you explain a little more, im still really new to android programming :) Thanks

Comment: It wont let me upload screenshots but i put the source for the app.

Comment: Try not setting your own WebViewClient and see if the behavior changes

Comment: I'll try that, i'll post later if it worked! Thanks alot for your help! :)

Comment: Hmm, If I do that it opens any links inside a new browser and still has the issue on the homepage.

Comment: Have you considered that it's an issue specifically with that webpage?  Have you tried other webpages and had the same issue?

Comment: I tried that same webpage inside a real browser and it worked, so I think its something to do with the app. I'll post screenshots as soon as I get 10 reputation lol.

Comment: Okay it turns out it was a problem with the webpage! But now its all working, so thanks for your help!

Comment: ahhah!  so the initial intuition was correct!  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    ((WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.webView)).saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```